# How to change value of MaskEditExtender's attribute Mask using javascript

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I have project in which i have textbox on which I have implement MaskEditExtender and set a value of Mask attribute like this

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
```

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$("#TextBox1").val('00.0000');
        debugger;
        document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = "00.0000";
    });
    function CallMe() {
        debugger;
        if (document.getElementById('CheckBox1').checked) {

            $find("MaskedEditExtender1").set_Mask("99.99");
            document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = "00.00";
        } else {
            $find("MaskedEditExtender1").set_Mask("99.9999");
            document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = "00.0000"
        }
    }
</script>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
    <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
    <%--<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
    </asp:ScriptManager>--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server"    onchange="javascript:CallMe()" />
      <asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" 
        TargetControlID="TextBox1" BehaviorID="MaskedEditExtender1"    Mask="99.9999"
       MessageValidatorTip="true" MaskType="Number"    InputDirection="LeftToRight"
    AcceptNegative="None" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" >
     </asp:MaskedEditExtender>
   </div>
    </form>
  </body>
   </html>
```

I have initialed text-box value in $(document).ready function. And my task is to change mask value on change of checkbox. This task i have done with a javascript function "CallMe". All of the code is work fine but when user click on text box. Textbox value change from "00.00" to "00.0000" i.e. initial value of Mask attribute of MaskEditExtender.

Please help me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
       <%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm1" %>
       <%@ Register TagPrefix="asp" Namespace="AjaxControlToolkit"     Assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" %>
        <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

       <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
     <head runat="server">

<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<title></title>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        //$("#TextBox1").val('00.0000');
        debugger;
        document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = "00.0000";
    });
    function CallMe() {
        debugger;
        if (document.getElementById('CheckBox1').checked) {
            $find("MaskedEditExtender1")._MaskConv = "99.9";
            //$find("MaskedEditExtender1").set_Mask("99.9");
            //$find("MaskedEditExtender1")._convertMask();
            document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = "00.0";
            alert($find("MaskedEditExtender1").get_Mask());
        }
        else {
            $find("MaskedEditExtender1")._MaskConv = "99.9999";
            //$find("MaskedEditExtender1").set_Mask("99.9999");
            //$find("MaskedEditExtender1")._convertMask();
            document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = "00.0000"
            alert($find("MaskedEditExtender1").get_Mask());
        }
    }

    function txtBox1_ClientClicked() {
       //            alert($find("MaskedEditExtender1").get_Mask());
       //            $find("MaskedEditExtender1").set_Mask("99.9");
      //            document.getElementById('TextBox1').value = "00.0";
        alert($find("MaskedEditExtender1").get_Mask());
    }
   </script>
   </head>
   <body style="height: 137px">
   <form id="form1" runat="server">
   <div>
  <asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" />
   <%--<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>--%>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" onclick="txtBox1_ClientClicked()"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" onchange="javascript:CallMe()" />
<asp:MaskedEditExtender ID="MaskedEditExtender1" runat="server" 
    TargetControlID="TextBox1" Mask="99.9999"
    MessageValidatorTip="true" MaskType="Number" InputDirection="LeftToRight"
    AcceptNegative="None" ErrorTooltipEnabled="True" >
</asp:MaskedEditExtender>
</div>
</form>
     </body>
 </html>
```

For changing mask value using javascritp we can use _MaskConv or .set_Mask("new value") and combine with _convertMask function.